# Query to select values from different rows and add them as columns to another table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
user {user_id, name}
family {child_id, mother_id, father_id, address, household_income}
```

I want to select a row in `family` given `child_id, mother_id and father_id` and have it return all the columns in `family` along with the 3 new columns for the names of the users associated with `child_id, mother_id and father_id`

```
family {child_id, mother_id, father_id, address,
        household_income, child_name, mother_name, father_name}
```

Is this possible?  I originally had the names along with the id in the family table but I felt that repeating the columns in both tables was redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

```
SELECT family.*,
       child.name  AS  child_name,
       mother.name AS mother_name,
       father.name AS father_name
FROM   family
  JOIN user AS child  ON  child.user_id = family.child_id
  JOIN user AS mother ON mother.user_id = family.mother_id
  JOIN user AS father ON father.user_id = family.father_id
WHERE  family.child_id  = ?
   AND family.mother_id = ?
   AND family.father_id = ?
```